# Function to calculate the period of a Mandelbrot Set point

Tags: complex-numbers, fractals, complex-dynamics

I'm trying to implement a program to calculate the period of a Mandelbrot Set point.

I'm using the multipliers of periodic points as explained here:

https://rlbenedetto.people.amherst.edu/talks/mhc_ug14.pdf

I've already implemented a first version but it's not detecting well all periods inside the bulbs.

I'm using this formula:

[image]

where "phi prime" is 2*z and "phi N" the Nth iteration of the Mandelbrot formula z²+c.

**UPDATE**:

I want to calculate the cycle of a point. Basically I want to build [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRBFO.png).

I'm not a mathematician but what I understood from the λ function, "n" is the minimum period/cycle of the orbit for the complex point "a".

The way to get the minimum "n" is by using brute force iterating "n" from 1 to MAX_PERIOD you want to check.

There is another explanation [here](https://github.com/jeremy-rifkin/mandelbrot-orbits) for this method to get the period.

LINKS:

- [The program I'm implementing](https://github.com/josecelano/mandelbrot-orbits-rust).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That property just telly you whether a periodic cycle is attrictive, repelling or indifferent, but it does not tell how to find such a cycle.  So maybe you are using the wrong formula?

Comment: I've added an update. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: As several others have pointed out, the multiplier for determining attractive/repulsive behavior really has nothing to do with it. You've really just got to code it, store a bunch of iterates and check against that. [Here's an Observable implementation](https://observablehq.com/@mcmcclur/orbit-detection-for-the-mandelbrot-set) that should help.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments already have stated, the value of $\lambda$ is not the period of the point $a$, but rather, it refers to a property of the dynamics of $a$; specifically, whether the $n$-cycle that $a$ belongs to is an attractive, repelling, or indifferent one.  What we mean by these terms is this:

- Attractive:  points in the attraction basin--loosely speaking, some neighborhood of the cycle of periodic points--will have a forward orbit whose limit will tend toward the cycle.  This is sort of analogous to the concept of a stable equilibrium in physics, where small perturbations away from the equilibrium will still return to that equilibrium.
- Repelling:  points in a neighborhood of the cycle are repelled from the cycle, even though the cycle itself is periodic.  This is like an unstable equilibrium (e.g., balancing a pencil on its tip is impossible but there is a theoretical point where the pencil's center of gravity is directly above the balancing point).
- Indifferent:  the dynamics of this case are complex--it's neither attracting nor repelling.  The ways in which orbits in a neighborhood of a cycle behave are not all the same.  See [how many known classifications and types of indifferent fixed-points are there?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172273/how-many-known-classifications-and-types-of-indifferent-fixed-points-are-there#2172346) for more information.

That said, all of this has nothing to do with the *period* of the cycle itself.  A naive calculation of the period would be done by calculating a sufficiently large number of iterations $\{z_0, z_1, \ldots \}$ and then comparing $z_n$ against $z_{n-k}$ for $k \in \{1, 2, \ldots, m\}$ where $m$ is the largest period you want to detect.  If you can find that $|z_n - z_{n-k}| < \epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$, this suggests a cycle of length $k$ and you would confirm by looking at $$\{|z_n - z_{n-k}|\}_{n=n'}^{n'+k}$$ and seeing that these are all sufficiently small. There are more sophisticated approaches, but this is the elementary way.

Comment: +1 For a mostly correct answer! I don't know that there are more sophisticated approaches, except in very special cases, though.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I was thinking one possible approach could be some Fourier analysis of the orbit, but I don't know if this is computationally efficient or if it has ever been implemented for a Mandelbrot plotting algorithm, so I didn't mention it.

Comment: @heropup what you suggested I think it is the classic cycle detection. I implemented one in C, and here is the explanation: https://github.com/josecelano/c-mandelbrot-arbitrary-precision/blob/master/doc/periodicity-checking.md. But if you calculate lambda for the nth interaction of the z²+c formula you can iterate n from 1 to m, where m is the largest period you want to detect. I finally make it work here https://github.com/josecelano/mandelbrot-orbits-rust/pull/8

Comment: @heropup What describes such notation? I mean last, after "... by looking at".

Answer (score 1):

What I do to create an image like the one you link, for $f_c(z) = z^2 + c$:

- start iteration from $z_0 := 0$, with $m := \infty$
- for each $n = 1, 2, 3, ...$ in order

  - calculate $z_n := f_c(z_{n-1})$
  - if $|z_n| < m$

    - set $m := |z_n|$
    - use Newton's method to solve $w = f_c^{\circ n}(w)$ with initial guess $w^{(0)} := z_n$ (this may fail to converge, in which case continue with the next $n$), the steps are $$w^{(i+1)} := w^{(i)} - \frac{f_c^{\circ n}(w^{(i)}) - w^{(i)}}{{f_c^{\circ n}}'(w^{(i)}) - 1}$$
    - calculate the derivative of the cycle $\lambda := {f_c^{\circ n}}'(w)$
    - if $|\lambda| < 1$, then the cycle is attractive and $c$ is within a hyperbolic component of period $n$, stop (success).  $\lambda$ may used as "interior coordinates" within the hyperbolic component. $w$ and $n$ can be used for interior distance estimation.

The point of using Newton's method is to accelerate the computation of $w$, a point in the limit cycle attractor.  Computing $w$ just by iterating $f_c$ could take many 1000s of iterations, especially when $\lambda$ is close to $1$.

I have no complete proof of correctness (but this doesn't mean I think it is incorrect; the images seem plausible).  It relies on the "atom domains" surrounding each hyperbolic component of a given period.

It also relies on the cycle reached by Newton's method being the same cycle as the limit cycle approached by iteration: this is true for the quadratic Mandelbrot set because there is only one finite critical point, $0$ ($\infty$ is a fixed point) and each attracting or parabolic cycle has a critical point in its immediate basin (see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3952801), which means there can be at most one attracting or parabolic cycle.

For an implementation in C99 you can see my blog post at https://mathr.co.uk/blog/2014-11-02_practical_interior_distance_rendering.html

Comment: I think that's more or less what I'm doing https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/58816/181915914-6d02230f-afc3-4c32-b7af-c66bcce4b28c.png. Your "d" is my "lambda". But I think I'm not using Newtons' method for the composition of "f". I did not know you could use it. Do you have more information about this method?

Comment: @claude Can you post a link to code that does it or put a sample code ?

Comment: @Claude Thx. Can you show values for which "my " algorithm fail and your will work ?

Comment: @Adam it's not so much about failure as efficiency.  for example, $c = \frac{1}{4} - 10^{-10}$ takes over $800000$ iterations to reach a fixed point in double precision floating point, but $20$ iterations of Newton's method suffice to reach a fixed point.  The two fixed points are slightly different, but both are fixed (each to themselves) in double precision.

Comment: @Adam, but with epsilon-based methods there may be other cases where a multiple of the true period is detected

Answer (score 0):

Here is "my" algorithm:

- choose parameter c
- compute critical orbit ( forward orbit of critical point ) and find period of it's limit cycle:

Steps:

- start with critical point: z = z0 = 0.0
- make n forward iterations of z0 to (possibly) fall into attracting cycle
  now z = zn
- make n forward iterations of zn to compute attracting cycle
- check backwards whether the last iterate z has already been visited before

Max iteration and precision ( epsilon ) might need to be adjusted
Here is [the code](https://github.com/adammaj1/period_complex_quadratic_polynomial) for complex quadratic polynomialand  for [the other polynomials](https://github.com/adammaj1/Describe-iterated-map-)

Comparison of "my" and Claude's methods:

| "my" | Claude's |
| --- | --- |
| compute z,n | compute z,n,lambda |
| gives only attracting z | gives all z, also repelling |
| checks dynamics by using forward iteration | uses numerical method for finding roots |
| need very small epsilon and very large n for points near boundary | can use bigger epsilon and smaller n |

Comment: You may need very small epsilon and very large n, otherwise for example $c = -\frac{3}{4} + 10^{-10}$ will probably give an incorrect period of $2$ instead of the correct period of $1$, which error will compound to an incorrect interior distance estimate (for example distance `3.8e-8` with your method (epsilon `1e-12`, n $79,573,343$) instead of `2e-10` with my method).  Haskell code: `head [ (n, z, d1, d2) | (n, z@[z0,z1,z2]) <- zip [0..] $ map (take 3) (Data.List.tails (iterate (\z -> z^2 + c) 0)), let d1 = abs (z0 - z1), let d2 = abs (z0 - z2), d1 < 1e-12 || d2 < 1e-12 ]`

Comment: @Claude ghci
GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> head [ (n, z, d1, d2) | (n, z@[z0,z1,z2]) <- zip [0..] $ map (take 3) (Data.List.tails (iterate (\z -> z^2 + c) 0)), let d1 = abs (z0 - z1), let d2 = abs (z0 - z2), d1 < 1e-12 || d2 < 1e-12 ]

<interactive>:1:110: error: Variable not in scope: c

Comment: `c = -3/4 + 10**(-10)`